# MD-5 checksum for http range requests

Tags: apache, md5

I am using apache server to server static files. The files could be large. I have written c++ program to download the file using http range request. (I have created 3 threads which fires 3 range requests to the same file). How do i make sure integrity of each range request? Apache doesn't send md5 header for range requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a HEAD request to the static file to get all the headers without the file. Maybe that also contains the MD5 checksum.

Also, some FTP sites have the md5sum of a file simply in a [text file](http://na.apachecon.com/downloads/acna_2011_slides.md5) along with the file.

It is not strictly necessary to check the MD5 of the file. TCP has checksums built-in, and it is very rare that a file gets corrupted on transfer.

Comment: The question is not about checksum of entire file. I know how this can be done in apache using contentDisposition directive. The part i am not clear is how to configure apache to send md5 checksum for range requests. Lets say i make 3 range requests to the same file request 1) GET sample.txt range 0-999 2) GET sample.txt 1000-1999 3) GET sample.txt 2000-